# How to fix the HTML Table <td> Images positioning irrespective of zooming the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

have two images inside     
On zooming the screen 2nd/last image goes down i.e. top bottom fashion.

I want to fix the span position so that on zooming in/out images should adjacent(side by side) to each other.

Comment: please send also code what you so far?

Comment: Please send your code or add in fiddle to better undersatnding.

Answer (score 1):

Remove bootstrap class on your html code 
and write manual css code like this

```
.your_class {max-width: 40%;}
```

This one for 350x150 
I guess you need max-width.
So you change for your image. I hope it will work